# How to create an "argument" that references another workbook/sheet in excel?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a workbook with cells that reference another file's sheet and cells; it appears that it is required that both files be open first, but I have a large number of cells that reference the same workbook and from day to day I need to update it to point to a different file for instance my formula might look like:

```
=['sillysheet 4-16-2018.xlsx']!A$35:A143
```

And I have several of these sorts of references though out the sheet; I'd like to be able to throw in an argument that replaces the `'sillysheet 4-16-2018.xlsx'` portion so that it's updated across all the cells in which it is referenced; I'd be happy retrieving it from a cell to be used as the argument and leaving the rest of the formula unchanged if possible for instance something like:

```
=[A1]!A$35:A143
```

...where `A1` contains `'sillysheet 4-16-2018.xlsx'`

or using `INDIRECT()` to construct it from concatenation of some sort.

```
=['sillysheet 4-16-2018.xlsx']!A$35:A143
```